# Pass Record ID from Account to Visualforce Page without Saving Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, urlhacking

I want to pass the Record ID to a visualforce page and reference that ID on an outputLink URL to take them back to the account. The User cannot "Save" the visualforce page, so how can I keep the ID?

FLOW:

Account page VF button ---> VF page to View Inventory Object Records ---> Select Inventory Record ---> OutputLink URL retains Inventory Record ID and adds Account ID so user is taken back to the Account with Inventory Record ID.

Since the VF page is just a view, How do I retain my Account ID? Is there a way for the Account ID to float around while choose the user chooses the Inventory Record ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the standard Account controller with my extension.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="naicssearchcontroller">
```

The standard controller retains the Account Record ID for use.

Answer (score 1):

If your Visualforce page is related to a standardController, like account, you can use the record data, like account id.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you answered yourself.